# How to add the full page parallax scroll on a one-page website

Tags: javascript, css, smooth-scrolling, parallax.js

I would like to add the full page `parallax scroll effect` on a one-page website, but I have no idea how to add this effect.

I have tried to set up the section `height: 100vh`, but the result goes out that the last section covers the above sections.

Do you have any suggestions? Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="twinkling"></div>
    <header>
      <div class="header-container">
        <h1>Constellations</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stargazing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="section1" class="background">
      <div id="crystal-animation">
        <figure>
          <img src="img/crystal.svg" alt="" class="crystal">
        </figure>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="background">
      <article class="content">
        <h2>What is Constellations?</h2>
        <p>Constellations are patterns in the night sky often formed by the most prominent stars to the naked eye. </p>
        <p>Constellations often carry names and take the shape of gods, hunters, princesses, objects and mythical beasts associated with Greek mythology – however, at times. </p>
        <aside><img src="img/crystal-animation.svg" alt="" class="crystal-animation"></aside>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" class="background">
      <h2 >12 Constellations</h2>
      <p>Click the constellation cards and understand more.</p>
      <div class="card">
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li><a href="aries.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/1.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="taurus.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/4.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="gemini.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/7.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="cancer.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/10.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li><a href="leo.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/2.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="virgo.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/5.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="libra.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/8.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="pisces.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/11.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li><a href="saguttarius.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/3.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="capricorn.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/6.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="aquarius.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/9.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="scorpio.html"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/12.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section4" class="background">
      <div class="s3-content">
        <h2>How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?</h2>
        <p class="s3">Using a star map will be your best bet for assisting in finding where to look for constellations, depending on your location and time of year. It’s different depending on where you live and on the seasons. You can also need the additional app to help find the constellations, that lets you enter your location and gives you a customized star map. </p>
        <p class="s3">All you need is a dark sky, so as far away from cities as possible, and for extra visual aide, a pair of binoculars or a telescope. With binoculars or a telescope, you’ll see fainter stars and other features like nebulae and star clusters. When you’re out observing, you’ll want to generally orient yourself towards the North Star.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   let hamburgerClicked = false;
   $("#toggle").on("click", function () {
      if (hamburgerClicked == false) {
         $(".top").css(
            "transform",
            "translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg)"
         );
         $(".middle").css("display", "none");
         $(".bottom").css(
            "transform",
            "translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg)"
         );

         hamburgerClicked = true;
      } else {
         $(".top").css("transform", "translateY(0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)");
         $(".middle").css("display", "");
         $(".bottom").css(
            "transform",
            "translateY(0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)"
         );
         hamburgerClicked = false;
      }
      $("#overlay").toggleClass("active");
      $("#overlay").toggleClass("open");
   });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(../img/background/background.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#meteor-shower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition-timing-function: .2s all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  display: block;
}

.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url(../img/background/2446101-03.png) repeat top center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
  -o-animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
  animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

header {
  height: 3em;
  position: fixed;
}

.header-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-container h1 {
  font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
}

.button-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 4px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.middle {
  top: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
}

li {
  animation: fadeInRight 0.5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.35s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  width: 30%;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}

#section1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 {
  :nth-child(1) {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
  }
}

#crstal-animation {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.crystal {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -46px;
  left: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg) rotateX(5deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 16px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg) rotateX(2deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 0px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(1deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 16px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
}

#section2 {
  padding: 60px 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 59%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.content p {
  width: 88%;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.crystal-animation {
  width: 68%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -56%;
  margin-right: -80%;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}

aside {
  display: block;
}

#section3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

#section3:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery {
  list-style: none outside none;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.gallery li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.svg {
  width: 75%;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px)rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#section3-content {
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition: .3s;
}

.intro h3 {
  font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
}

.content-text {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.constellation-img {
  opacity: .35;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: -80px;
  position: relative;
}

.constellation-star {
  width: 56%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.intro {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  color: floralwhite;
}

.constellation-pattern {
  width: 11%;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.intro p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.constellation-icon {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.constellation-icon li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.constellation-button {
  width: 50%;
}

.constellation-button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 205, 0.7);
  filter: brightness(3);
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 205, 0.7);
}

.constellation-button:active {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 205);
  filter: grayscale(.2);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.constellation-star-aq {
  width: 46%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.constellation-star-ca {
  width: 36%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(16deg);
}

.constellation-img-ca {
  opacity: .35;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}

.constellation-star-ge {
  width: 36%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.constellation-img-leo {
  opacity: .35;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}

.constellation-star-leo {
  width: 40%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.constellation-img-sc {
  opacity: .35;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: -20px;
  position: relative;
}

#section4 {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.s3 {
  text-align: left;
}

.s3-content {
  width: 74%;
  padding-top: 16%;
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

Here is a rough working demo on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ha3c04yL/4/

Comment: Could you please improve your question by providing an adequate code snippet that suits your desired behavior? Omit code that's not necessary for your question.

Comment: I am sorry! I am not sure what code that's not necessary for my question, so I post them all. 

I would like to set 4 sections on my one-page site. When I scroll down,  it will scroll down in full screen (from the above section to the below section).